# How to access a superclass method in octave?

Tags: oop, inheritance, octave

I'm working with objects in octave and I would like to call the superclass set method in the subclass set. In the GNU octave documentation I haven't found how its works so I've tried to use the [matlab documentation](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/calling-superclass-methods-on-subclass-objects.html) syntax but I get the next error: *'' undefined near line 20 column 5* where the call is.

¿How could I access the superclass method correctly?

Here the code:

```
function s = set (o, varargin)

s = o;
if (length (varargin) < 2 || rem (length (varargin), 2) != 0)
  error ([mfilename "  ::::  Expecting property/value pairs."]);
endif

while (length (varargin) > 1)             #We get the first 2 pairs while exist.            
  prop = varargin{1};
  val  = varargin{2};

  varargin(1:2) = [];
  if (strcmp (prop, "color")) 
    if (ismember (val, ["black", "red", "green", "yellow", "blue", "violet", "cyan", "white"] ))   #We check if val is a correct color.
      s.color = val;
    else
      error ([mfilename "  ::::  Expecting the value for ""color"" to be a correct color."]);  
    endif
  else
    set@entity (s, prop,val);
  endif
endwhile

endfunction
```

I'll add more details:

A simple example could be the next two classes:

try1, constructor and method (in his folder @try1):

```
 function t = try1(x)
    t.n = x;
    t = class (t, "try1")
 endfunction

function o = op(t,x)
    o = t.n + x;
endfunction
```

try2 inherits from try1, constructor and method(in his folder @try2):

```
 function t2 = try2(x)
    t1 = @try1(x);
    t.n = x;
    t2 = class (t, "try2",t1);
 endfunction

function o = op(t,x)
    o = t.n - x;
endfunction
```

How to acces to op method of try1 with an instance of try2?

thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access the constructor of the parent class, just call it as you would normally outside the child class. Like so:

```
$ cat @try1/try1.m 
function t = try1 (x)
  t.n = x;
  t = class (t, "try1");
endfunction
$ cat @try1/op.m 
function o = op (t)
  disp ("op() from try1");
  o = t.n + 5;
endfunction
$ cat @try2/try2.m 
function t2 = try2 (x)
  t1 = @try1 (x);
  t.n = x;
  t2 = class (t, "try2", t1);
endfunction
$ cat @try2/op.m 
function o = op (t)
  o = op (t.t1);
endfunction
$ octave
octave:1> try2 (5)
ans = <class try2>
octave:2> op (ans)
op() from try1
ans =  10
```

See the manual section on [Object Oriented Programming](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Object-Oriented-Programming.html), specially the section on [Inheritance and Aggregation](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Inheritance-and-Aggregation.html)

Comment: With that syntax, I only get a succession of unspecific errors where the call is. Moreover, I've read that page and I can't find a reference to that syntax.

Comment: @JorgeGarcía can you give a full minimal reproducible example?

Comment: A simple example added to the question.

Comment: @JorgeGarcía I have fixed the answer to address your specific example.

Comment: The problem is that syntax doesn't work in octave. If I try that, I receive errors like "error: mrdivide method not defined for try1 class" or "error: binary operator '/' not implemented for 'function handle' by 'scalar' operations" (it depends of if I call "@try1/try1(x)" or "@try1/op(x)". I think octave is tryiing to call the function and then divide the output.

Comment: @JorgeGarcía forget the `@try/try1 (x)`. Did you check my modified answer? It works in Octave and there is no `@try/try1 (x)` (note that the first few lines, the ones starting with `cat` are on bash, just to display the contents of the files).

Comment: Yes. It's like you say but I don't understand how could it allow to use try2 the method op of try1.

Comment: @JorgeGarcía on your example you only made use of the constructor. I changed it again for the other methods. The class folder (which you are using) are quite limited. I think you need to keep the other object around to call the parent. Also, the documentation you found was for classdef (which is another very different syntax for object oriented programming in Octave).

Comment: It works! I didn't know that the parent class was a part of the child class structure but it seems very logic. Thanks! :)

Comment: @JorgeGarcía I still think you should have to keep an object of the parent class in your structure. I have asked on the [Octave help mailing list](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-octave/2016-02/msg00132.html) and other people have commented which may be of interest to you.

Comment: It will be very helpful to call outside the class folder. Thanks :)